# Jade: Best practice with classes and ids

Tags: html, pug, template-engine

I've searched for a while now, but I couldn't find an answer.

To create a div container with a class or id in Jade you can write:

```
.foo
#bar
```

or

```
div.foo
div#bar
```

Another thing is multiple classes:

```
div.foo.bar
```

or

```
div(class="foo bar")
```

What's best practice or is it just personal preference?

Answer (score 0):

It is just a shorthand notation. Nothing wrong with it, just more readable for users who are unfamiliar with the shorter syntax to implicitly show that you are creating a `div`.

In some cases, using a shorthand syntax however causes the interpreter to perform better, because it works a bit different [under the hood](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/134118/why-are-shortcuts-like-x-y-considered-good-practice). 
I'm not familiar with how Jade works, but maybe using just the dot notation saves some work behind the scenes, whilst using the more explicit instructions takes more time to parse.

Same as something similar in css:

```
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
border-color: red;

/* shorthand */
border: 1px solid red;
```

Or javascript:

```
var foo;
if (true){
   foo = "bar";
} else {
   foo = "not bar";
}

// shorthand
var foo = true ? "bar" : "not bar";

var x = x + 1;
// shorthand, and might uses the processor or engine differently
var x += 1;
```